How to dynamically handle display of page numbers with respect to Pagination? : ReactJS
I'm no coder or dev but I have a website that was made by someone else and the pagination is getting out of hand.
Image:
As you can see, I currently have 17 pages that are showing up on my nav pagination but I'd like it to only show 10 of them when you are on page 1, and when you press page 2, I'd like it to change the max page to page 11; when I am on page 3 I want the max page shown to be page 12, and so on.
I'm not sure how to properly explain it but I want the minimum and max pages that are displayed to increase dinamically, sort of like this:
At page 1: Prev 1 2 3 4 5 Next
At page 5: Prev 3 4 5 6 7 Next
I took a look at this thread but I still can't figure it out because the coding is so different from what my website is using(?)
This is the .jsx code:
function NewsRow(props) {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAllPosts = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("/api")
        setPosts(res?.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }

    fetchAllPosts()
  }, [posts.length])

  //save new entries when adding new post on site
  const saveNewEntryHandler = (enteredData) => setPosts(prevPosts => [enteredData, ...prevPosts])

  //PAGINATION
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
  const recordsPerPage = 4
  const numberOfPages = Math.ceil(posts.length / recordsPerPage)
  const lastIndex = currentPage * recordsPerPage
  const firstIndex = lastIndex - recordsPerPage
  const paginatedPosts = posts.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex)
  const numbers = [...Array(numberOfPages + 1).keys()].slice(1)

  const prevPage = () => { if (currentPage !== 1) setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1) }
  const changeCurrentPage = (id) => setCurrentPage(id)
  const nextPage = () => { if (currentPage !== numberOfPages) setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1) }


  return (
    <div className={styles.content_column} >
      <ImageCarousel />
      <Welcome />

      <NewsInput onSaveNewEntry={saveNewEntryHandler} fullList={posts} />

      {paginatedPosts.map((object) => (
        <NewsCard
          key={object.id}
          id={object.id}
          title={object.title}
          date={object.date}
          description={object.description}
          image={object.img} />
      ))}

      <Pagination>

        <PaginationItem
          className={'paginationItemStyle'}>
          <PaginationLink onClick={prevPage}>Prev</PaginationLink>
        </PaginationItem>

        {numbers.map((i, key) => (
          <PaginationItem
            key={key}
            className={'paginationItemStyle'}
            active={currentPage === i }>
            <PaginationLink onClick={() => changeCurrentPage(i)}>
              {i}
            </PaginationLink>
          </PaginationItem>
        ))}

        <PaginationItem
          className={'paginationItemStyle'}>
          <PaginationLink onClick={nextPage}>Next</PaginationLink>
        </PaginationItem>

      </Pagination>

    </div>
  )
}

export default NewsRow

and this is the .scss:
.paginationItemStyle {
    &.page-item {
        button {
            background-color: rgba(47, 53, 59, 0.5);
            border-color: #000000;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        &.active, &:hover {
            button {
                background-color: rgb(47, 53, 59);
                color: rgb(34,138,252);
            }
        }
    }
}

I know that what needs to be changed is the const numberOfPages = Math.ceil(posts.length / recordsPerPage)  but I have no idea to what exactly I need to change it to and the person that made me the site is out of reach.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
I looked around thge internet for solutions such as in this thread but I can't find a "code" that matches my own.

Replace your numbers with this:
    const maxElements = 10;
    const numbers = [...Array(numberOfPages + 1).keys()]
      .slice(1)
      .slice(currentPage - 1, Math.min(currentPage - 1 + maxElements, numberOfPages));


Thank you for your help! This has partially solved the issue xD Now at the start, it only shows 10 pages. However, when I click on other pages, it increments the number of pages displayed on the pagination instead of updating the page numbers while keeping 10 pages displayed in the pagination.
https://i.imgur.com/yV9SyES.png
https://i.imgur.com/7Hbpmul.png
https://i.imgur.com/Tc0QkUC.png
Is there anything else I need to add to fix that?

Because in your question you want to "increase the maximum page number" hence my answer. Just updated the answer

Oh I'm sorry, that was my bad! I didn't specify because I had linked to another thread that had the same issue has me. Your new edit now loock the pages at number 10 and doesnt show pages 11+ and higher. I have edited my post to include proper details of what I actually want to have displayed ;u;

I'm not sure what you've edited. So you don't want to show pages that has already passed while keeping the number of pages displayed as 10?

Example: at page 1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], at page 2: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

I had edited and added the example now! Yes, it is as you just said

Try my answer again, I updated

Solved! Thank you so much for your time and patience!
